# Working with buttons in a grid

Tags: user-interface, events, button, gwt

I am using GWT 1.6 and I am pretty new to it.

My question is about the use of a button as part of a grid row. 
How can the onClick method that the button has refer to the data in the grid? 
How I can make the button be aware to its raw and the other data that exists on the same row?

Comment: little fix... (i wrote the question late:)

my question is simple: in a button on a grid 
1. how do i know which row was created?
2. how the onClick method access the data in the table?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Adding anonymous click listeners refer to outer data (declared "final" of course).
2. Keep Map (or Map) and one reusable click listener. Perhaps using some button id as a key would be better.
3. In a listener refer to button's element and walk through DOM to the parent  and down to required data.
4. In some GWT extensions have data to list/grid/tree items binding mechanisms.

Do you need some details about options above?